# React hooks does not work in Gatsby components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

I try to do a simple menu toggle. And it works - but only with react classes. 
When I want to use functional components the initial state is set (but not in the chrome react debug tool) but the toggleExpanded function dont`t change the state at all.

I tried even a basic example from the actual react website:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This also does not work. But when I form it to a class - all is fine.

What can that be - is that a normal behavior of gatsby components?

Comment: Did you try with arrow function syntax? Maybe it will work fine. `const Example = () =>`

Comment: I tried it now - same. Does not work at all.

Comment: @Gawel1908 that wouldn't make a difference

Comment: react version is - 16.8.1 - react hooks should work - I guess

Comment: There's no such thing as a “Gatsby Component”. It's literally just React.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution was - I had to upgrade the version of all packages.

`yarn upgrade`

after that - the hooks worked ;)